# Convert HttpPostBasicFile to Image in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I get a picture by uploading and I want to convert it to image file without save it.
how can I do it?

```
public HttpPostedFileBase BasicPicture { get; set; }

var fileName = Path.GetFileName(BasicPicture.FileName);
// store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
 var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
BasicPicture.SaveAs(path);
```

By this code I can save the picture on the server but I want convert it to image
like

```
Image img=(Image) BasicPicture;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Give us a bit more than that. Work with us. :) How have you uploaded the file? Show us some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) method:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromStream(BasicPicture.InputStream))
{
    ... do something with the image here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert **HttpPostedFileBase** to **WebImage** (which gives you more API - like method Resize):

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{

    if(file != null)
    {

        var image = new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage(file.InputStream);

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), file.FileName);

        image.Save(path);

    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hello Could you tell me how to reverse it If I have webImage how to make it HttpPostedFilebase ?

Answer (score 0):

With out knowing exactly what you are doing and why i can give a full intelligent answer.

Personally i would use something like this to open an image. You have saved the image to your server, so instead of casting why not new up a new image? the end result is the same!

`WebImage webImage = new WebImage(path);`